# C program to find individual words in a string using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I am writing a program where I use strtok in order to find each word in a string that I type into the command line, in my example, my code is called command.c so when I type:

```
./command.out "Hi, there"
```

I should get as my result:

```
Arg = "Hi, there"
Next word "Hi,"
Next word "there"
```

so far my code will complete the arg part of the print statement, but will not use execute the latter part in order to separate the string in question, my code currently is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i;

  for(i =1;i< argc; i++)
    printf("Arg = %s\n", argv[i]);
    char delims[] = " ";
    char *word = NULL;
    word = strtok(argv[i], delims);

    while(word != NULL) {
      printf("Next word \"%s\"\n", word);
      word = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix this code? Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the curly braces around the `for` block:

```
for(i =1;i< argc; i++)
{
   printf /* ... and so forth */
}
```

Comment: Silly python syntax strikes again.

Comment: @Student: Happens to the best. But seriously, get an editor and learn how to use it. It'll save you *heaps* of time and headache in the future. (Notepad doesn't count.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code indentation is wrong, this may cause your problem.

The 'for' statement affects only the next line, the printf one, so variable 'i' increases later to value '2', then when you ask for argv[i], you're asking for argv[2], you should call argv[1].